# How to import/include cpp file Xcode cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, xcode, import, include, cocos2d-x

This image is "HelloWorldScene.cpp"
[enter to look image](http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/wV0WJbQ5iyejeEOM)

How to use Import/include .cpp file on .cpp file or some different way to solve?

`#include <ClassA.cpp>` error this line and other .cpp line file.

Comment: You don't need to include the cpp file if you are including the header.

Comment: For files not located in a directory your compiler knows about use quotes not <>.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain What i can use?

Comment: @Cartoon เอาแหมละ You probably would write some simpler C++ desktop programs first. Then you would probably want to write a small library for Android and ios to do what you need and abstract away the implementation details. Here is where I learned C++ from: http://www.youtube.com/user/antiRTFM/videos

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain and Josh
now i can solve this problem.
thank you.